# Best Practice for Storing this in MongoDB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, mongodb

As part of a research project for work, I am doing some (greatly simplified) comparisons between SQL Server and MongoDB.  I am familiar with SQL server, but this is my first foray into Mongo.  I am curious as to what best practice is for this.

Imagine a Blog site.  Users can log in and post blogs.  They can also comment on blogs, or reply to other comments.  The table structure in SQL looks roughly like this:

```
Users
========
id
Name
Password

Blogs
=========
id
Title
Content
AuthorUserId

Comments
=========
id
Content
AuthorUserId
BlogId
ParentCommentId
```

Straightforward enough, I guess.  If ParentCommentId is NULL, then the comment is in direct reply to the Blog, otherwise, ParentComment is another comment which is being replied to.

I use a nifty little recursive function to Delete a comment that's far down in the tree, which also deletes any child comments associated with it.

So in Mongo, I currently have a Users collection with the same fields.

The part I'm wondering about is Blogs/Comments.

My initial impulse was to store comments as a Subcollection of the Blog.  The problem comes when Comments start replying to other Comments.  There is no practical limit on the "depth" of a reply tree.  So if I store Comment replies as a Subcollection of a Comment, and so forth, even after say 4 replies, we are at:  Blog -> Comment -> Comment -> Comment -> Comment -> Comment, or a Sub-sub-sub-sub-subcollection.

Since Mongo doesn't seem to have a recursive query/delete - this gets unworkable fast.

So here's where I'm stumped.  Aside from working through some basic tutorials, I have never worked with Mongo before, so I'm not really sure how to accomplish this without mimicking a relational structure, which seems to be defeating the purpose of using a non-relational database a bit.

So uh.  Help?

TIA.

Comment: What you said would be the way I would store it in mongo if I were you. I don't understand why you need a recursive query/delete... ? Every time you query the blog, you'll want it's comments and subcomments as sub-documents since it "actually" does have a tree like structure, and when you delete a comment, it will delete all the sub-documents of that comment which is what you probably want to happen since the sub-comments won't be relevant anymore without their 'parent' comment.

Comment: The "blog and comments" question is frequently asked. The MongoDB docs talk about the various options: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/ ... If comments were stored as separate documents for example, you could do a query for a particular ancestor and delete docs that had the ancestor.